# 'UnityEngine.GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for `Transform' error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i was making a script to generate the paths on which my player is to run just like an endless runner. i was trying to access my "own" transform (player's tranform) and put it in playertransform variable but getting this error. heres the full code:-

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class tilemanager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] tileprefabs;

    private Transform playertransform;
    private float spawnz = 0.0f;
    private float tilelength = 16.0f;
    private int amountoftilesonscreen = 7;
    private List<GameObject> activetiles;
    private float safezone = 15.0f;

    void Start(){

        activetiles = new List<GameObject>();
        playertransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player").Transform;

        for(int i = 0; i < amountoftilesonscreen; i++){

            SpawnTile();
        }
    }

    void Update(){

        if(playertransform.position.z - safezone > (spawnz - amountoftilesonscreen * tilelength)){

            SpawnTile();
            DeleteTile();
        }
    }

    void SpawnTile(int prefabIndex = -1){

        GameObject go;

        go = Instantiate(tileprefabs[0]) as GameObject;
        go.transform.SetParent(transform);
        go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * spawnz;
        spawnz += tilelength;
        activetiles.Add(go);
    }

    void DeleteTile(){

        Destroy(activetiles[0]);
        activetiles.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: FindGameObjectsWithTag returns an Array and Transform is not a property of the Array class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `FindGameObjectsWithTag()` which returns array of `gameObject`. Change it to `FindWithTag()`.

and correct code would be :

```
playertransform = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag returns a gameobject array. Use GameObject.FindWithTag instead.

Answer (score 0):

if your script is a component on the object you want to find can you just refer to it as
`transform`:

```
transform.position;
```

and if you want to have it in a variable just use:

```
Transform transform_off_object = transform;
```